# Issue with my script to add users from a text file on centOS7

Tags: linux, bash

I'm setting up a server and adding users and was self teaching how to add a batch of test users with no passwords. So I have a file with first and last names in `username.txt` like:

```
james bond 
bobby dennis
alex newell
jon temple
joshua bridal
paul spears
```

I try to run this script and it says unexpected error in line 8.

```
#!/bin/bash
while user in 'cat userlist.txt'
do
  USER_LIST="$(cut -d " " -f 1,2,3 userlist.txt --output delimiter='.')"
  echo "$USER_LIST" | while read user;
  do useradd "$user"
done
```

The outcome I'd like is username `:james.bond`. That'ss the format I'm looking for. If I can get that to work then I can add a random number generator at the end.

I am a very weak scripter so most of this stuff i have found online and am trying to piece it together.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Bob, try adding an example for your `userlist.txt` file:

    cat <<EOF > /tmp/userlist.txt
    James Bond
    Sherlock Holmes
    Hercule Poirot
    Name Surname
    Another One
    The Sixth
    Seven Dwarfs
    Finally Eight
    EOF

Comment: Your script only has 6 lines. Please show the real script and real error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's create a sample for your `userlist.txt`, using a FIRSTNAME LASTNAME format:

```
cat<<EOF > /tmp/userlist.txt
james bond
sherlock holmes
hercule poirot
name surname
another one
the sixth
seven dwarfs
finally eight
EOF
```

now, you can make a simpler loop than the original:

```
cat /tmp/userlist.txt | while read firstname lastname ; do 
   echo useradd -m "${firstname}.${lastname}" ; 
done
```

the output is going to be:

```
useradd -m james.bond
useradd -m sherlock.holmes
useradd -m hercule.poirot
useradd -m name.surname
useradd -m another.one
useradd -m the.sixth
useradd -m seven.dwarfs
useradd -m finally.eight
```

when you find out that you are satisfied with the result, just remove the `echo` used for debugging:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /tmp/userlist.txt | while read firstname lastname ; do 
  useradd -m "${firstname}.${lastname}" ; 
done
```

the `read` builtin command expects strings separated by spaces.

Comment: this was perfect thank you very much i like the debugging step you added, I ordered the Linux pocket guide so i can learn more about this and doing more scripting things. thank you again

Comment: And the *random number* part ? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: so I was thinking what if 2 james bonds were to wanting to be on the server. I could avoid that with adding 4 random numbers on the end..i kinda did it by doing .$(RANDOM%999)  after last name.  It really isn't important for now, but i was kinda just toying around.

Comment: Think about having a counter. `james.bond`, `james.bond.1` and such. It's going to be interesting toying with this counter, it will help you increase your scripting.